# Is there a converse to `operator.contains`?

Tags: python

edit: I changed the title from `complement` to `converse` after the discussion below.

In the [**`operator`**](https://docs.python.org/3/library/operator.html) module, the binary functions comparing objects take two parameters. But the `contains` function has them swapped.

I use a list of operators, e.g. `operator.lt`, `operator.ge`.

They take 2 arguments, `a` and `b`.

I can say `operator.lt(a, b)` and it will tell me whether `a` is less than `b`.

But with `operator.contains`, I want to know whether `b` contains `a` so I have to swap the arguments.

This is a pain because I want a uniform interface, so I can have a user defined list of operations to use (I'm implementing something like Django QL).

I know I could create a helper function which swaps the arguments:

```
def is_contained_by(a, b):
    return operator.contains(b, a)
```

Is there a "standard" way to do it?

Alternatively, I can implement everything backwards, except `contains`. So map `lt` to `ge`, etc, but that gets really confusing.

Comment: Great question. I don't think the complement operation exists in python.

Comment: `operator.contains` matches the signature of the `__contains__` method; it's the right-hand argument (the container) that determines how containment is defined. (That is, `a in b == b.__contains__(a)`.)

Comment: I think it's more like the *reflection* of `contains` that you're asking for than the complement. The complement would be a `does_not_contain` function. But maybe there's terminology I'm not familiar with.

Comment: How exactly are you presented the arguments that you "need" to swap them?

Comment: @khelwood Maybe "complement" is the right word here. In the way that `a < b` and `b >= a` are complements.

Comment: I would call the relationship between `<` and `>=` a "negation", i.e. `>=` is the negation of the `>` relation. I don't think there's a broadly accepted word for the relationship between `<` and `>`, though "dual" or "obverse" would probably be pretty safe choices IMHO.

Comment: @SilvioMayolo ["converse"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Converse_relation).

Comment: @chepner I have an actual value and a desired value (along with the comparison). So, I'm given the actual number 5, and want to check that it's e.g. >= 3, or that it's contained in a set {1, 2, 7}.

Comment: Unless you are getting a tuple like `t = (3, [1,2,3])` and plan to write `contains(*t)`, I don't see where your problem with passing the arguments in the right order lies.

Comment: @chepner I don't know what the "right order" is at the time of calling the binary function. I have a dictionary lookup of function objects which take two parameters. They don't know what the right order is. Most of them are `a, b`, but `contains` is `b, a`, so I need to write a little wrapper and store that in the lookup instead. I just wondered whether something like `operator.in_` existed. It does seem to be an omission. I like @khelwood and @Code-Apprentice's comments about `in_` and consistency with `and_` and `or_`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If either of them posts an answer, you should accept that, but between users @chepner and @khelwood, they gave you most of the answer.

The complement of `operator.contains` would be something like `operator.does_not_contain`, so that's not what you're looking for exactly. Although I think a 'reflection' isn't quite what you're after either, since that would essentially be its inverse, if it were defined.

At any rate, as @chepner points out, `contains` is not backwards. It just not the same as `in`, `in` would be `is_contained_by` as you defined it.

Consider that `a in b` would not be `a contains b`, but rather `b contains a`, so the signature of `operator.contains` makes sense. It follows the convention of the function's stated infix operation being its name. I.e. `(a < b) == operator.lt(a, b)` and `b contains a == operator.contains(b, a) == (a in b)`. (in a world where `contains` would be an existing infix operator)

Although I wouldn't recommend it, because it may cause confusion with others reading your code and making the wrong assumptions, you could do something like:

```
operator.in_ = lambda a, b: b.__contains__(a)
# or
operator.in_ = lambda a, b: operator.contains(b, a)
```

That would give you an `operator.in_` that works as you expect (and avoids the `in` keyword), but at the cost of a little overhead and possible confusion. I'd recommend working with `operator.contains` instead.

Comment: I've been following this question today and after reading your answer, I wonder why there is no `operator.in` to reflect the same argument ordering as the `in` operator.

Comment: @Code-Apprentice There can't be an `operator.in` because `in` is a keyword. They could call it something else (probably `operator.in_`), but evidently they avoided that by flipping the operands and using `contains` instead.

Comment: @khelwood Oh right...that makes sense. Maybe `operator.__in__` then?

Comment: @Code-Apprentice In line with `operator.is_` and `operator.not_`, it would presumably be `operator.in_`.

Comment: @khelwood Makes sense. I also see `operator.and_` and `operator.or_`.

Comment: `__in__` would suggest that it's a magic method like the other dunders, so yeah `in_` would have made some sense.

Answer (score 4):

If your goal is uniformity, we can go way more general than a helper function that works specifically for `contains`.

```
def flip(f):
  return lambda y, x: f(x, y)
```

Now `flip(operator.gt)` will behave (on any sane class) just like `operator.lt`, and `flip(operator.contains)` is the function you want.

Comment: Flipping `gt` will give you `le`, not `lt`.

Comment: @PeterWood Nah.

Comment: @KellyBundy my mistake, I'm getting old

Comment: *Negating* `gt` gives you `le`.